# JavaScript - How to get label names and Urls in String based on Colon?

Tags: javascript

Sample String:

```
var demoString="Extract the URLs and Lables from String Google:https://www.google.com Yahoo:http://yahoo.com";
```

I would like to able to extract some portion of the provide string like(Google,https://www.google.com,Yahoo,http://yahoo.com)

How can I achieve this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a [Regex expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/). These expressions specify rules for matching text.

In this case you could use the following Regex expression (you can try it [here](https://regexr.com/4tkhv)):

`[A-Za-z0-9]+\:https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)`

- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` matches the site name (with no spaces)
- `\:` matches the colon
- `https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)` matches any URL starting the http or https (taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/1943263)

To use this in Javascript you would do something like this:

```js
var demoString="Extract the URLs and Lables from String Google:https://www.google.com Yahoo:http://yahoo.com";

var regexPattern = /([A-Za-z0-9]+)\:(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))/g;

var matches = demoString.match(regexPattern);

console.log(matches);
```